# Atualizar uma DIV específica, sem dar refresh na página

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails

#### Como atualizar uma DIV sem dar refresh na pagina toda?

Antigamente no rails 2.3.10, usava-se o 'remote_function' para dar um update numa determinada div.

Agora no rails 4.2, já que não possiu mais o 'remote_function' como poderei fazer isso?

#### Ex: Ao digitar um ID

'<%= text_field :individual_id, (algo como :update => 'search') %>'

#### Aparecerá o nome da pessoa desse ID

div id='search'

'<%=h @molecular_bio.individual &&
@molecular_bio.individual.name %> '

/div'

Tentei usar esse comando em javascript, mas não sei muito de js.

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>`

`<script type="text/javascript">`

```
var live_search_timer = null;


function start_live_search(){

    clearTimeout(live_search_timer);
```

`live_search_timer = setTimeout(function(){`

`$('#search').fadeOut('slow').(comando para dar um update na div).fadeIn('slow');`
`}, 2000);`
`}`

`</script>`

`<%= text_field :individual_id, :onKeyPress => "start_live_search()" %>`

Comment: Você já tentou utilizar ajax ( Jquery ou JavaScript ) para fazer essa atualização?

Comment: Sim, já tentei. Vou editar a pergunta com o codigo em javascript que eu tentei

Comment: Olá Michael, acabei de responder uma pergunta com conteúdo relacionado usando JQuery e Ajax, espero ajudar-te, esse é o link: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/144104/executar-php-sem-atualizar-toda-a-p%C3%A1gina

Answer (score 1):

Crie uma função JS

```
function updateDiv(div) {
    var div = '#' + div;
    $(div).load(window.location.href + " " + div);
}
```

ou faz direto pelo console

```
 $('#div').load(window.location.href + " " + '#div');


<div id="teste">
```

Answer (score 0):

usando o unobtrusive javascript em rails
[links](https://www.google.com.br/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=rails+unobtrusive+javascript&oq=rails+unob&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.7334j0j7&gws_rd=cr&ei=io-qV_7eLIKowASnlLS4DQ)

#view

```
<% form_tag @molecular_bio, url:edit_molecular_path(@molecular_bio) :method => :get, :remote => true do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<div id='search'>

<%=h @molecular_bio.individual && @molecular_bio.individual.name %> 

</div'>
```

#controller

```
def edit
  @molecular_bio = MolecularBio.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.js {}
  end
end
```

#edit.js.erb

```
$('div#search').html('<%= escape_javascript(@molecular_bio.individual && @molecular_bio.individual.name) %>')
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 <script>
      setInterval(function(){
        $('#ID_DIV_PARA_ATUALIZAR').load('PAGINA_A_SER_CARREGADA_NA_DIV.php');
      }, 1000) /* tempo em MS para atualizar*/
    </script>
```