# Executar PHP sem atualizar toda a página

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, pdo

Meu código é esse:

```
<?php
$buscarusuario=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM top5 WHERE status = 'ativo' ORDER BY colocacao ASC");
$buscarusuario->execute();

// Exibir com Fetch_Obj
$linha=$buscarusuario->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
foreach ($linha as $listar) {

?>

<!-- INÍCIO TOP -->

  <div class="col-md-12 wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
    <div id="top5-caixa">
      <div class="colocacao">
      <?php echo $listar->colocacao; ?>
      </div>
      <div class="musica-cantor">
        <p class="cantor"><?php echo $listar->cantor; ?></p>
        <p class="musica"><?php echo $listar->titulo; ?></p>
      </div>
      <div class="like">
        <a href='extra/likes.php?id=<?php echo "".$listar->id.""; ?>' alt="Gostei"><img src="images/like.png" height="40px" width="40px" id="like"></a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div><!-- ./ COL-MD-12 -->
<?php } ?>
</div><!-- ./ ROW -->
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Inserir dados PDO</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
// Incluindo arquivo de conexão
include("conexao.php");
$pdo = conectar();
// Recuperando valores
$id = $_GET['id'];

// Realizando consulta
$atualizartop=$pdo->prepare("UPDATE top5 SET likes = likes +1 WHERE ID='$id'");
$atualizartop->bindValue(":id",$id);
$atualizartop->execute();
if($atualizartop->rowCount() > 0):
    echo "Obrigado por votar!";
else:
    echo "Desculpe, mas ocorreu algum erro.";
endif;

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Gostaria de saber se ao clicar no link para votar teria como retornar um "Obrigado por votar!" sem ter que atualizar para a página que tem a função php.

Se alguém souber como ajudar agradeço.

Comment: Para retornar essa mensagem, tem que ter a certeza de que a gravação foi correta. Para isso, tem que ter o script da gravação no início do programa, não no fim, onde recebe uma mensagem e em uma div receba essa mensagem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coloque um `id` na sua imagem com o valor `like`. Em um arquivo de extensão `.js`, vai esse código:

```
$("#like").click(function(){
//evento de click sobre a imagem

    var id = $(this).attr('id'); //aqui você pegao valor do atributo id
    $dados['id'] = id; //esse array será passado para o php só que por POST ao invés de GET

    $.ajax({

        url: "incrementaLike.php", //Aqui vai o nome do seu arquivo PHP
        type: "post",
        async: true,
        data: $dados,
        cache: false
     })
     .done(function(data){

        //neste o ponto, o código php já foi executado e voltou para aqui se tudo ocorreu sem erro
        console.log(data);
     })
    .fail(function(){

        //vem para cá se algum erro ocorreu
        console.log("Deu alguma errada no php");
    });
});
```

Você deve separar seu PHP em um arquivo separado e o caminho para este vai no atributo `url`.

No caso eu coloquei um arquivo chamado **incrementaLike.php** na mesma pasta do seu `html` e também dos arquivos `js`.

**incrementaLike.php**

```
<?php

include("conexao.php");
$pdo = conectar();
// Recuperando valores
$id = $_POST['id'];

// Realizando consulta
$atualizartop=$pdo->prepare("UPDATE top5 SET likes = likes +1 WHERE ID='$id'");
$atualizartop->bindValue(":id",$id);
$atualizartop->execute();
if($atualizartop->rowCount() > 0):
    echo "Obrigado por votar!";
else:
    echo "Desculpe, mas ocorreu algum erro.";
endif;

?>
```

Comment: Desculpe-me, acabei esquecendo, no caso você quer mostrar uma mensagem, você deve mostrar dentro do .done(), caso alguma coisa ocorra de errado, não em termos lógicos no PHP, a função vai para o .fail().

Comment: Olá Leandro. Agradeço sua resposta, mas eu infelizmente fiquei boiando aqui pois não manjo muito de javascript. Teria como você fazer um exemplo para que possa entender? No código eu quero somar o valor de uma coluna ao clicar na imagem "like". Queria entender como adaptar a essa função. Desde já obrigado.

Comment: Tudo bem, primeiro baixe esse arquivo https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js e inclua ele na sua página, é uma biblioteca chamada JQuery.

Comment: Já tenho ela no meu código. Pois algumas funções do site necessitam da mesma. O problema é que não entendo muito bem como funciona o javascript

Comment: Alterei a resposta, troquei só o get pelo post no seu PHP

Comment: Meu amigo você me deu uma luz enorme. Entendi como é pra funcionar o javascript agora. Porém quando cliquei na imagem não aconteceu nada. Coloquei o id="like" na imagem e retirei o <a> do link que estava utilizando para atualizar. O que pode ter ocorrido?

Comment: Se você tem um link que engloba sua imagem na hora que você clica ele executa o evento padrão do link ignorando o evento da imagem, boa sorte com as suas ideias!

Comment: Sempre lembre de finalizar a questão para ajudar a comunidade StackOverflow