# Como retornar valor do PHP sem que haja necessidade de recarregar a página?

Tags: php, xml, post

A princípio eu achei essa pergunta **[Executar PHP sem atualizar toda a página](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/144104/executar-php-sem-atualizar-toda-a-p%C3%A1gina?answertab=active#tab-top)**, que me deu uma noção, porém não me ajudou a resolver o problema. É o seguinte: Na pagina **pag_mensagens.php** será carregado todos contatos do usuário, ao clicar no contato o sistema enviará via Ajax para **adminMensagens.php**, lá ela executará todos códigos para encontrar/ criar xml e afins. O problema é na volta, pelo que eu testei o PHP está funcionando (criando e salvando o xml), só que eu não sei como fazer pra voltar uma "autorização" para a página **pag_mensagens.php** executar o PHP que irá carregar o xml. (Só pra deixar claro que eu tenho noção de como funciona a interação Cliente/Servidor). (Tentei a fazer a volta dessa "autorização" com o post do php em **adminMensagens.php**, porém lembrei que teria que recarregar a página, mas esse não é o foco). (Se alguém puder me ajudar, é urgente pro TCC).

Código da **pag_mensagens.php**:

```
        <div id="a" class="contatos"><center>Contatos</center>

            <?php
            foreach ($contatos as $contato):
                if ($contato['estadoContato'] != 'Desativado') {
                    echo '<div id = "contato' . $cont . '" class = "contato" onclick="abrirMensagem(event); ">';
                    if ($contato['nome'] === null) {
                        echo 'vazio';
                    } else {
                        echo '<center>' . $contato['nome'] . '</center>';
                        echo '<img src="fotos/' . $contato['foto'] . '" width="40px" height="40px">';
                        $_SESSION['contato' . $cont] = $contato[$cpfxml];
                    }
                    echo '</div>';
                }
                $cont++;
            endforeach;
            ?>

        </div>
        <div id="b" class="mensagem"><center>Mensagens</center>
            <?PHP
            // tentativa com o Post
            if (isset($_POST['nomeXML'])){       
                $nomearquivo = $_POST['nomeXML'];
                $dom = $_SESSION['dom'];
                $dom->load($nomearquivo);
                $_SESSION['dom'] = null;
                $ver = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
                foreach ($ver as $xml):
                    echo "<center><p>" . $xml->mensagem . "</p></center>";
                endforeach;
            }
            ?>

        </div>
        <div class="enviarMensagem">
            <form>
                <input type="text" name="txtmsg" placeholder="Digite sua mensagem"><input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="btn">
            </form>
        </div>
        <style type="text/css">
            .contatos
            {
                width: 300px;
                height: 600px;
                background-color: blue;
                float: left;
                overflow:auto;
            }
            .contato
            {
                width: 290px;
                height: 100px;
                margin-left:5px;
                background-color: yellow;
                float: left;
            }
            .mensagem
            {
                margin-left:400px;
                width: 600px;
                height: 600px;
                background-color: red;
                overflow:auto;
            }
            .enviarMensagem
            {
                margin-left:400px;
            }

        </style>
        <script>
            function abrirMensagem(event) {
                $.post("adminMensagens.php", {
                    cpfContato: event.target.id, cpflogado: <?php echo $cpf; ?>
                }, function (msg) {
                    $("#teste").html(msg);
                })
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Código da página **adminMensagens.php**:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
require_once 'conexao.php';
require_once 'banco-mensagens.php';
session_start();

// para carregar a mensagem
if ((isset($_POST['cpfContato'])) && (isset($_POST['cpflogado']))) {
    $cpfContato = $_POST['cpfContato'];
    $cpfContato = $_SESSION[$cpfContato];
    $cpflogado = $_POST['cpflogado'];
    // <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
    $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0", "ISO-8859-7");
    lerXML($dom, $conexao, $cpfContato, $cpflogado, $_SESSION['tipoUsuarioLogado']);
    $_SESSION['dom'] = $dom;
    mandarNomeXML($_SESSION['nomeXML']);
}

function mandarNomeXML($nomeXML) {
    $content = http_build_query(array(
        'nomeXML' => $nomeXML,
    ));
    $context = stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => $content,
        )
    ));
    $result = file_get_contents('pag_mensagens.php', null, $context);
    return $result;
}
```

Código da banco-**mensagens.php** (arquivo onde estão as funções, caso seja necessário):

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

function listarContatos($conexao, $cpf, $tipo) {
    $contatos = array();
    if ($tipo == 2) {
        $sql = "select * from carregarContatoTec where cpf_cliente_fk = $cpf";
    } else {
        $sql = "select * from carregarContatoCli where cpf_tecnico_fk = $cpf";
    }
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
    while ($contato = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
        array_push($contatos, $contato);
    }
    return $contatos;
}

function addMensagem($documento, $mensagem, $cpf_origem) {
    // criar msg
    $msg = $documento->createElement("msg");
    // criar nó data
    $data = date('j/n/Y H:i:s');
    $dataElm = $documento->createElement("data_envio", $data);
    // criar nó origem
    $cpf_origemElm = $documento->createElement("cpf_origem", $cpf_origem);
    // criar nó mensagem (texto)
    $mensagemElm = $documento->createElement("mensagem", $mensagem);

    $msg->appendChild($dataElm);
    $msg->appendChild($cpf_origemElm);
    $msg->appendChild($mensagemElm);
    return $msg;
}

function gerarNomeXML() {
    $dir = "xml_msg";
    $novonome = $dir . "/" . md5(uniqid(time())) . ".xml";
    return $novonome;
}

function lerXML($dom, $conexao, $cpfCli, $cpfTec, $tipo) {
    if ($tipo === 2) {
        $sql = "select caminho_xml as xml from tbl_mensagem where cpf_cliente_fk = $cpfCli and cpf_tecnico_fk = $cpfTec";
    } else {
        $sql = "select caminho_xml as xml from tbl_mensagem where cpf_cliente_fk = $cpfTec and cpf_tecnico_fk = $cpfCli";
    }
    $return = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($return, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $nomeArquivo = $row["xml"];
    if (!file_exists($nomeArquivo)) {
        $novonome = gerarNomeXML();
        guardarXML($conexao, $novonome, $cpfCli, $cpfTec, $tipo);
        $msg = addMensagem($dom, "Conectados!", null);
        // criando nó principal
        $root = $dom->createElement("mensagens");
        // adiciona a mensagem ao root
        $root->appendChild($msg);
        // adiciona o root ao xml
        $dom->appendChild($root);
        // retirar os espaços em branco
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        // gerar código ??
        $dom->formatOutput = true;
        $_SESSION['nomeXML'] = $novonome;
        $dom->save($novonome);
        return $root;
    } else {
        // carrega o arquivo
        $dom->load($nomeArquivo);
        $_SESSION['nomeXML'] = $nomeArquivo;
        // recupera nó principal
        $root = $dom->documentElement;
        return $root;
    }
}

function guardarXML($conexao, $caminho, $cpfCli, $cpfTec, $tipo) {
    if ($tipo == 2) {
        $sql = "update tbl_mensagem set caminho_xml = '$caminho' where cpf_cliente_fk = $cpfTec and cpf_tecnico_fk = $cpfCli";
    } else {
        $sql = "update tbl_mensagem set caminho_xml = '$caminho' where cpf_cliente_fk = $cpfCli and cpf_tecnico_fk = $cpfTec";
    }
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
    return $resultado;
}
```

Comment: Na pag_mensagens.php: tem um formulário e tem também uma função `abrirMensagem(event)` Como a função é disparada? e o formulario faz o que? Não estou vendo coerência.

Comment: O formulário agora é inútil, usarei ele para enviar uma nova mensagem futuramente. a função **abrirMensagem** é executada ao click da Div.

Comment: agora que eu vi lá no foreach, rs

Comment: E ao clicar na div essa função faz o que tem que fazer?

Comment: Ela envia para **adminMensagens.php** o cpf do usuário logado e do contato que foi clicado, lá ela roda todo o **lerXML**, coloca o nome do xml e o dom na sessão, e deveria retornar uma forma de autorizar que o cógido que está na **div mensagens** fosse executado.

Comment: Essa função aqui comigo não funcionou, estou fazendo outra

Comment: Só uma observação, eu tirei o get e coloquei um if para verificar se **$_SESSION['dom']** estava vazia, daí quando clico na div e recarrego a página, o xml abre, porém tenho que recarregar a página...

Comment: Esse código da div mensagens pode ser executado em outra página? Só tem session nela

Comment: Pode, mas teria que acompanhar a select do banco, se não o cpf do usuário logado não apareceria em **adminMensagens.php**.

Comment: Então, a pagina adminMensagens.php vai retornar para a pag_mensagens.php: uma "autorização", o que seria essa autorização, tipo "manda brasa" ou alguma variavel que tem lá

Comment: Já montei um equema, testei e tá rodando beleza

Comment: Poderia me mandar o link dele no Github para eu tentar implementar?

Answer (score 0):

> Não vejo como a `adminMensagens.php` passar uma "`autorização`" para a `pag_mensagens.php` executar um código PHP. Você pode, de posse dessa "`autorização`", invocar outro ajax para executar esse PHP em outra pagina, ou mesmo para `adminMensagens.php`, é só fazer uma condicional nela passando os devidos parâmetros.
>   Pode também realizar de uma só vez todas as etapas da adminMensagens.php  mais o PHP da **div mensagens**

Vou postar a resposta com duas requisições porque talvez seja necessária para o o seu desenvolvimento. No mais, como dito acima, é possível modificar.

**Código da pag_mensagens.php:**

```
    <div id="a" class="contatos"><center>Contatos</center>

        <?php
        foreach ($contatos as $contato):
            if ($contato['estadoContato'] != 'Desativado') {
                echo '<div id = "contato' . $cont . '" class = "contato" onclick="abrirMensagem(event); ">';
                if ($contato['nome'] === null) {
                    echo 'vazio';
                } else {
                    echo '<center>' . $contato['nome'] . '</center>';
                    echo '<img src="fotos/' . $contato['foto'] . '" width="40px" height="40px">';
                    $_SESSION['contato' . $cont] = $contato[$cpfxml];
                }
                echo '</div>';
            }
            $cont++;
        endforeach;
        ?>

    </div>

.........................
.........................

<script language="javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    $(function(){
        $('.contato').click(function(){
            //id da div clicada
            var id = $(this).attr('id');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "adminMensagens.php",
                data: {cpfContato: id, cpflogado: "<?php echo $cpf; ?>"},
                // essa function success será executada se a requisição for feita com sucesso
                success: function(data){
                // coloca o conteúdo retornado da consulta da pagina adminMensagens.php - valor da variavel $nomeXML - na div id="resultado"
                $('#resultado').html(data);

                   /*******envia  para divMensagens.php,
                   pode ser o retorno - valor da variavel $nomeXML - da adminMensagens.php ou o que você quiser,
                   por exemplo uma string; altere postNomeXML: data por postNomeXML: "string"
                   ou uma variavel postNomeXML: variavel ***********************************/

                             $.ajax({
                                url: 'divMensagens.php',
                                type: 'post',
                                data: {
                                   postNomeXML: data
                                },
                                success: function(returnhtml) {
                                    $("#result").append($('</p>').html(returnhtml));
                                }
                            }); 

                },
                error: function(){
                  // essa funcion error será executada caso ocorrer algum erro na requisição
                  $("#resultado").html("Ouve um erro");
                }   
            });

            event.preventDefault();

            return false;

        });
    });
});

</script>

..................
..................
```

**Código da página adminMensagens.php:**

```
<?php
......................
......................

 //o que será enviado para a pag_mensagens.php

 echo $nomeXML;

 //que por sua vez vai enviar para a divMensagens.php

?>
```

**Código da página divMensagens.php**

```
      <div id="b" class="mensagem"><center>Mensagens</center>
        <?PHP
        // tentativa com o Post
        if (isset($_POST['nomeXML'])){       
            $nomearquivo = $_POST['nomeXML'];
            $dom = $_SESSION['dom'];
            $dom->load($nomearquivo);
            $_SESSION['dom'] = null;
            $ver = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
            foreach ($ver as $xml):
                echo "<center><p>" . $xml->mensagem . "</p></center>";
            endforeach;
        }
        ?>

    </div>
```

> Se unificar `adminMensagens.php` e `divMensagens.php` use apenas o primeiro ajax

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção, mas mesmo assim não foi. Infelizmente pela urgência irei deixar sem Ajax ou nem implementarei esse sistema no TCC.

Comment: @Leandro, alguma coisa tá bugada por ai, comigo funciona redondinho! você adicionou a biblioteca?

Comment: Sim, vou tentar revisar a parte que eu desenvolvi, qualquer coisa aviso..